# Payment link in Civi invoice

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

Our organization hosts events and has memberships individuals sign up for on our website. If someone signs up for a membership or registers for an event online they have two options for payment. They can choose to "pay now" on the registration page or they can choose "invoice me". We do not currently utilize the invoice feature in Civi. Instead we have our accounting department send an invoice to the requesting party. We would like to begin using Civi Invoice. However, we noticed there is no online payment functionality (i.e. payment link) in the link or email.

Is this something we would need to enable or is there a plug in that would allow us to send invoices that contain a payment link in the invoice or email? If not, does anyone have a work around process for allowing members to pay for membership online via an invoice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Default invoice payment page" setting which is used to set contribution page that can be used to pay pending or partially paid contribution using payment processor.

More about the setting and uses:

Wiki: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=346750980

Here is how you can achieve this

1. Create a Contribution Page by enabling Other amount and payment processor.
2. Navigate to Administer >> CiviContribute >> CiviContribute Component Settings and select contribution page create at #1 for **Default invoice payment page**
3. Create a contribution for a contact with **pending** status.
4. On User Dashboard of contact (/civicrm/user?cid=[contact_id]) under contribution section you will see pay now button against the pending contribution. When clicked on pay now it will redirect to online contribution page where one can pay pending contribution online using credit card.
   [image]
5. You can also generate the link to pay pending contribution online `http://domainname.com/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=[contribution_page_id]&ccid=[contribution_id]`

where contribution_page_id(id) is contribution page id created at #1 and contribution_id(ccid) is contribution id created at #3.
6. You can use this link to send in invoice for people to pay online.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: thank you for this. However, we would need to use multiple different contribution pages as we have several different event/membership types we would like to use this for. Are you aware of any way to use multiple invoice pages as opposed to just 1?

Comment: @pradeep - great answer - does the Invoice and Tax feature need to be enabled to do this?

Comment: i don't see the link for Default invoice payment page even after turning it on.

Comment: For 4.x version of Civi to enable 'Pay now' you needed Invoice and Tax to be enabled. But not for 5.x. This button is now only visible if the contribution status is Pending.

Comment: The link you have above [to send to people to pay their invoice online] does not work -> I think it needs to be: /civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=[contribution_page_id]&ccid=[contribution_id]&[contact.checksum]&cid=[contact_id]

Comment: KarinG if you want to pay as anonymous user than you need checksum and contact id i guess or probably the link might need more parameter due to recent change